# Help Uninstalling Stubborn Application

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I have the original Motorola Droid. I recently installed Lotus Notes Traveler on it (we use Lotus Notes at work). The application is giving some issues, so I was going to uninstall it and re-install it. Unfortunately, when I try to do that I get a message the message "Uninstall Not Succesful". Is there any way to uninstall an app that does not want to uninstall through "Manage Applications"?

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: No, I have not rooted this phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the Lotus Notes Traveler app makes itself the Device Administrator on the phone.  You need to disable this before uninstalling it.  The following quote is from [Lotus FAQ](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/How_do_I_uninstall_the_client_on_an_Android_device_LNT8521):

> You should uninstall Lotus Notes Traveler by launching the Lotus®
>   mobile installer application, then selecting the Lotus Notes Traveler
>   application and choosing uninstall.
>
> If you choose to uninstall
>   manually and your device is running Android 2.2 or above, you must
>   first disable the device administrator. To do so, select Menu >
>   Settings > Location & Security > Select device Administrators. After
>   you have disabled the Lotus Notes Traveler device administrator, you
>   can use the operating system to remove Lotus Notes Traveler, by
>   navigating to Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage Applications.
>
> You can uninstall Lotus Mobile Installer using the normal method for uninstalling
>   applications on your Android device.

Answer (score 2):

I would install the Android SDK on your PC and attempt the uninstall through ADB:

`adb uninstall packagename`

`packagename` is probably something like `com.ibm.lotusnotes`, I don't know the exact name since it doesn't appear to be publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finally uninstall using Titanium Backup's Force uninstall feature

Answer (score -1):

If you have ROM Manager installed, try doing a "Fix Permissions"

Comment: Fix Permissions from ROM Manager requires root.  According to OP, his phone is not rooted.