# Unable to uninstall apps

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, uninstallation

I am unable to uninstall any application on my Samsung Galaxy S. I have tried all possible ways (settings-applications-manage applications-uninstall and with the edit option). These applications are the normal ones downloaded from market.

But whenever I reboot my phone those applications are still there in my phone and its as if nothing has changed.

Also I keep getting this "settings.google.application has stopped unexpectedly" and am not able to open any of my apps.

I tried formatting my internal SD card by connecting it to the PC but that also didn't work.

Comment: Sounds like you may have to do a factory reset.

Comment: Did you try to uninstall the apps with root permissions?

Answer (score 1):

(converted from a comment to an answer)

This might be a file-system problem.

I once got an overfull yaffs2 files system on /data to get frozen and wasn't able to delete/move/update anything. By executing 'dmesg' in a terminal or via adb you could clearly see it, was full of yaffs panic msgs.
Formatting was the only option (aka. factory reset).

Comment: As to ADB: see [Matthew Read's answer to *Help Uninstalling Stubborn Application*](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/12396/4281).